# Don't sync certain password with iCloud

Tags: icloud, keychain

Is there any way to specify that a certain password should not be synced to iCloud?

Use case:

> I am allowed to have internet only on one mac address. So I use it on my laptop, but the password is synced to iCloud and so iPad also joins the network (which it cannot use as there is mac protection). Can I restrict that password to be available only on the Mac?

Answer (score 2):

So if you look in the *Keychain Access*, there is a "Keychain" column, and initially your password ends up in both *System* and *iCloud* keychains. You should delete the *iCloud* entry, this will remove the password form the other devices, but the one with *System* will stay and will be used by your machine

[image]